# Moved docker-compose.yml creates a new postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have set up a Postgres database on docker on ubuntu with the docker-compose.yml just for that database within the folder `~/postgres` and I'd run `docker-compose up -d` to run my database from within the `~/postgres` folder.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - database.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  database-data:
```

This database is set up and working perfectly, so I decided to set up my web application as well and, because the `docker-compose.yml` file was inside that folder, I moved it outside to `~/` so I could use it for my web app as well.

This is what the `docker-compose.yml` in `~/` looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - postgres/database.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  webapp:
    image: webapp/site
    build:
      context: ./retro-search-engine
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        buildno: 1
    links:
      - "database:db"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8000:80"
    volumes:
      - webapp:/var/www
    environment:
      db_host: db
      db_username: xxxx
      db_password: xxxx
      db_database: xxxx
      db_port: 5432

volumes:
  database-data:
  webapp:
```

As you can see, the database docker configuration is basically the same, the only thing that changes is the path to the `database.env` file since it's still in the previous folder.

So, the problem here is that when I run `docker-compose up -d` from `~/`, everything starts normally but when I access the database, all of my tables are gone.

If I go back to `~/postgres` and do `docker-compose up -d` in that folder (with the previous `docker-compose.yml`) and connect to the db, I can access my tables.

So what I think is happening is that it's either creating a new container or somehow the folder where the data is stored is relative to the `docker-compose.yml` file and it's creating a new database because it can't find the old files.

I have no idea how to solve this issue, I have googled around and couldn't find anything so I decided to ask here before I dump my whole db and restore it into a new container, which I don't want to do because it's a 16gb database and it's gonna take forever.

Does anyone have any idea how I can use my new docker-compose.yml with the data from my database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### First:

- Replace : `postgres/database.env` by `./postgres/database.env`
- Use `docker compose up --build` :
  *it will rebuild the image (usefull if you made some change to your dockerfile).* try to avoid to use -d when developing, you'll avoid to have tons of container running.

### Second:

I suggest you to follow the following reco, It will resolve your problem and it will be cleaner if you want to use a pipeline CI/CD and to create more "autonomous" image and container on demand.

```
rootfolder
|-docker-compose.yaml
|-postgres/
|  |--All_other_files_for_the_postgres_docker_image
|-webapp/
   |-- Dockerfile
   |-- All_other_files_for_the_webapp_docker_image
```

bellow you will find my "correction" :

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres"
    container_name: "my_postgres_container"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./postgres/database.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  webapp:
    image: webapp/site
    container_name: "my_webapp_container"
    build:
      context: ./retro-search-engine
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - "database:db"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8000:80"
    volumes:
      - webapp:/var/www
    environment:
      db_host: db
      db_username: xxxx
      db_password: xxxx
      db_database: xxxx
      db_port: 5432

volumes:
  database-data:
  webapp:
```

If you want to use an existing postgres image that is already present (to see if an image already existe you can do : `docker image | grep postgres`)

then you can do directly in your docker-compose :
image: "<your_image_name>"

Comment: database-data is a volume, there is a difference between volumes and mounts. In most cases volumes are better than mounts for databases. Other then that i was about to suggest replacing postgres/database.env by ./postgres/database.env as you suggested, you were ahead of me :). Fix your answer and i'll vote up

Comment: doing it ! thx sir

Comment: Also the compose file

Comment: Thank you for reading twice time behind me :)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work, I get this error when running `docker-compose up --build`:
Building database
ERROR: no build stage in current context

I have an empty dockerfile in the postgres directory because I'm using the raw postgres image.

Comment: I updated the docker compose by removing the build context. you can copy/paste again the docker-compose code.